# .NET Core 2.1 Web Scraper Console Outputting "HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to create a web scraper with .NET Core 2.1 & HtmlAgilityPack that pulls League of Legends stats from na.op.gg.

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace WebScraper
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            {
                MainAsync(args).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
        }
        async static Task MainAsync(string[] args)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync("http://na.op.gg/summoner/userName=Mr%20BalIoon%20Hands");
            var pageContents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            HtmlDocument pageDocument = new HtmlDocument();
            pageDocument.LoadHtml(pageContents);

            var champWinRate = pageDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"SummonerLayoutContent\"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]");

            Console.WriteLine(champWinRate);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

For the XPath, I simply went onto Chrome, inspected element, and copied the XPath for a win rate statistic.

When I run my program, I get the following console output:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong... any ideas? Thanks so much!

Comment: champWinRate is an object. Try inspecting one of it's properties like `InnerText`.

Comment: @mr.coffee LOL, that worked. Thank you!!

Comment: Your welcome. I added my comment as an answer if you would like to mark your question as answered :)

Comment: @mr.coffee For sure, it won't let me mark for another 8 mins, but I'll be sure to do so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

champWinRate is an object. Try inspecting one of it's properties like `InnerText`.